# What is the relationship between a docker image ID and the IDs in the manifests?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I am trying to understand the connection between the image ID as reported by `docker images` (or `docker inspect`) and the actual layers or images in the registry or manifest (using v2).

I run docker images, I get (abbreviated and changed to protect the not-so-innocent):

```
REPOSITORY                                             TAG                 IMAGE ID
my.local.registry/some/image      latest              abcdefg
```

If I pull the manifest for the above image using the API, I get one that contains `fsLayers`, not one of which matches the (full) ID for the image. I get that, since the image is the *sum* of the layers.

However, if I pull that image elsewhere, I get the same ID. If I update the image, push and pull it, the new version has a new ID.

I thought it might be the hash of the manifest. However, (a) pulling the manifest via the API does not return the hash of the manifest in the JSON, and (b) looking in the registry directory itself, the sha256 of the given manifest in `/var/lib/registry/v2/repositories/some/image/_manifests/tags/latest/current/link` (or those in `index/sha256/`) give the correct link for the manifest that was downloaded, but does not match the image ID.

I had assumed the image ID matches the blob, but perhaps I am in error?

Comment: This may be of interest; image-ids in docker 1.10 will change for content-addressability; https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/17924, and the related design document; https://gist.github.com/aaronlehmann/b42a2eaf633fc949f93b

Comment: So, the image ID is (was?) a content hash, whereas the layers referenced in the manifest are distribution hashes? What is the image ID a content hash of? Is it the topmost layer? The entire FS after all layers are applied? The former seems strange, since I could create identical hashes (content or distribution) and hence image IDs just by building 2 images with different lower layers but identical top layer, like https://gist.github.com/deitch/62cfbf5572c0382a87f5

Comment: Digging a bit deeper, if I do `docker history` on an image ID, I get the layers that were built. Those should correspond to the `fsLayers` in the manifest, where the image ID in history is the *content* hash, and the layer in the manifest is the *distribution* hash?

Comment: @thaJeztah can you help some more?

Comment: @thaJeztah did some more experimentation. The content header hash is identical to that returned by `docker pull`, but different from that returned by `docker images` or `docker inspect <image>`. What is the relationship?

Comment: When I do a push an image to our private registry, the (layer) hashes do not overlap with those I get when I pull the same image from that registry.  Is this part of your question, deitch?

Comment: Part of it, yes. This whole thing started with a private registry, then I released a Ruby gem to interact with any registry (pub or priv), then wanted to do pull/push without interacting with the engine, which means need to know how the hashes work. Answer: poorly documented.

Comment: Check this [blog](http://windsock.io/explaining-docker-image-ids/) on the final section. It might help answer your question.

Comment: Is there a definitive answer to this question?

Answer (score 7):

When we push an image into a registry,

1. We create a manifest that defines the image - layers inside it, and push both the manifest and layers independently.
2. We compress the layers and only then push them.

So in our host the hashes we have are the hashes of the content present in those layers, called the **Content Hashes**.

But to the registry we send the compressed layers, due to which the *content* changes and so the hashes change. So before those compressed layers are sent, the hashes for the compressed layers are calculated which are called the **Distribution Hashes** and those hashes are put in the manifest file.

Due to the difference in these Content and Distribution hashes, you see a difference in the ids.